# write glue pypspark errors to text file

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, aws-glue

I’m trying to add some error handling to my code.  I’m running pyspark code inside of aws glue jobs.  What I would like to do is create a text file when there is an error and then write a short message and the error out to the text file.  I have an example of what I’ve tried below.  When I run the try/except code it returns an error that there’s no such file or directory.  The workaround that I’ve come up with is to create a dynamic frame and add a column to it with the error message as a string.  I got to think there is an easier way to do this.   Does anybody know a better way write the error messages out to a text file as part of a try/except block in glue pyspark?

example tried Code:

```
for i in [1,0,3]:


    try:
        print(1/i)

    except Exception as e:

         logf=open('s3://xxxx/error_logs/error_test.log',"a")


         logf.write("failed {0}: {1}\n".format(str(i), str(e)))


         logf.close()
        print(e)

        pass
```

work around Code for writing out to csv:

```
log_txt = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", {'paths': ["s3://xxxx/error_logs/"] }, format="csv" )


log_txt_df=log_txt.toDF()

log_txt_df=log_txt_df.withColumn('try',lit('test'))

log_txt_df.show()
```

Comment: You should use boto3 s3 apis to access s3 and not python file apis

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
error_message = "your error message"
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket, file_key).put(Body=error_message )
```

Whenever an error is thrown, save the error in an object and write it to the file.
Here bucket = s3 bucket name, while file_key = name and path of the file.

Comment: Please provide context around your answer to avoid "low-quality" review now and in the future. (End of Review).